# Remove/update checked items: mysql, best practice

Tags: mysql

For example, I have on the web-page list of items with checkbox and users can check many of them to perform some action (delete, set state (active, inactive), etc). Users can check even 100 items at once or even more. So, should I execute 100 or more sql-queries?

Update:
E.g. in gmail you can checked many letters as read/unread or delete them.

Comment: We'll need to know more. This doesn't give us enough information.

Comment: I need only a logic / algorithm, I don't need a code, e.g. I have wrote small update in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the  `id`s from the records that should be deleted/updated and use `in()` to perform the operation you like. For instance:

```
delete from your_table
where id in (1, 3, 5, 99)
```

and

```
update your_table
set `state` = 'inactive'
where id in (1, 3, 5, 99)
```

Comment: Would be this query very slow if user checked 100 ids or even 500?

Comment: I don't think so. But if you have a big range of `id`s I suggest using `between`: `where id between 1 and 399`

Comment: I can't be sure that id will be at range 1-500, most of all a range will be between 1 and 1 000 000...

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you do not update database using asynchronous calls.

The SQL can look something like this:

```
UPDATE `articles` SET active = 1 WHERE `articles`.`id` IN (3, 4, 10, 230, 12, 32)
```

Comment: Would be this query very slow if user checked 100 ids or even 500? :)

Comment: No, I don't. 100 asynchronous calls - this is very bad idea.

Comment: The speed depends on your DB schema, number of records etc, but probably there is no faster way to achieve this.

Comment: Ok,thanks! Anyway, I can break my id list as no more than 100 id in one query.